# Why did my TableView get shifted up?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, keyboard

[image: TableViewCell gets shifted up when keyboardIsShown]

I have a method that gets called when the keyboard is shown. It's working on other view. Somehow the TableView gets shifted up.

```
-(void) keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *) notification {
// -- return if keyboard is still shown
MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
if ([sharedManager.keyboardIsShown isEqualToString:@"YES"]) return;
NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];

//---obtain the size of the keyboard---
NSValue *aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
CGRect keyboardRect = [self.view convertRect:[aValue CGRectValue] fromView:nil];

//---resize the scroll view (with keyboard)---
CGRect viewFrame = [scrollView frame];
viewFrame.size.height -= keyboardRect.size.height;
scrollView.frame = viewFrame;

//---scroll to the current text field---
CGRect textFieldRect = [currentTextField frame];
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:YES];
sharedManager.keyboardIsShown = @"YES";
```

}

Comment: How do you expect it to look like ?

Comment: How do you lay out your views?

Comment: Can you post your `autoresizingmask` for the tableview?

Comment: The purpose is to resize the scrollView accordingly with the keyboard size. Such that content will not be unreachable when keyboard is shown. Everything is behind the scrollView. I am using a UIViewController.

Comment: @Derek Lee Its 18. Set it to 0 and its solved. Though I have no idea what it does...

Comment: This question is barely related to an `UITableView` or cells. I changed the tags accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `myTableView.autoresizingMask = 0;` did the trick.